# How do I change the mouse's i-beam cursor in Xcode 7.3

Tags: macos, xcode, cursor

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014986/changing-the-mouses-i-beam-cursor-in-xcode-5) to this on Stack Overflow regarding Xcode 5, however, the solution no longer works.

I would like to change my IBeam cursor in Xcode to use [this cursor](http://www.dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff) instead.

### Question

How do I change my mouses Ibeam cursor in Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution that works for me thanks to a GitHub link provided by [@aldryd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036611/aldryd):

- https://github.com/egold/better-xcode-ibeam-cursor/issues/16

GitHub user [sokobania](https://github.com/sokobania) provides the following steps:

1. Download ThemeEngine from: https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine
2. Run ThemeEngine in Xcode and you may be presented with a few errors.

   1. Failed to code sign "ThemeEngine".

      - **Just click Fix Issue**
   2. Nullability specifier '_Nonnull' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'NSString'; did you mean to apply the specifier to the pointer?

      - **Allow Xcode to Resolve**
3. We'll need to remove some derived data from Embedded Binaries. Click your root **application > Targets > General > Embedded Binaries** and *remove* the top item:

   [image: Embedded Binaries in Xcode screenshot]
4. Run **ThemeEngine** and select "Open Document", you'll need to locate your **Assets.car** file in Xcode here:

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/R‌​esources/Assets.car
   ```
5. Once loaded, find **DVTIbeamCursor** in the list and drag your IBeam of choice over Xcode's default Ibeam.

   [image: DVTIbeamCursor]

   I like use the Ibeam provided by [@TheTC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026038/thetc): 
   [dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff](http://dracoventions.com/images/external/TIbeam.tiff)
6. Select "**Save As...**" and overwrite Xcode's **Assets.car** file with the new file. I had to save the copy to my desktop and then drag the new Assets.car file into the Xcode folder to overwrite.

Comment: I've used this cursor replacement in Xcode for over a year and it's great. I can't get it to work in 7.3, though. They just updated it but I still can't get it working. When it works, it's nice.

Comment: Thx @DanBeaulieu I'll check it out.

Comment: I followed all the steps and it worked like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's egold's ibeam solution updated for Xcode 7.3...

https://github.com/ebaker355/better-xcode-ibeam-cursor

Worked beautifully for me.

Comment: I'll use this method to install on my iMac and see how it goes. Thanks.